# Sp_oamethod to upload file with size greater than 8000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is part of my procedure to return `@v_buffer` variable.
Problem is that, the size of file i want to upload is greater than 8000 bytes. That's why i need to use `varbinary(max)` type.
But sp_oamethod read returns me an error.
Is someone know hot to use sp_oamethod to solve my problem?

```
declare @returnCode int
declare @v_file int
declare @v_buffer varbinary(max)
declare @v_fullpath nvarchar(400) --pdf file phusical location

exec @returncode = sp_oacreate 'adodb.stream', @v_file out  

exec @returncode = sp_oamethod @v_file, 'open'  

exec @returncode = sp_oasetproperty @v_file, 'type', 1

exec @returncode = sp_oasetproperty @v_file, 'loadfromfile', @v_fullpath  


exec @returnCode = sp_oamethod @v_file, 'read', @v_buffer out, -1
if @returncode <> 0  
begin  
    exec sp_oageterrorinfo @v_file
end  

exec @returnCode = sp_OAMethod @v_file, 'Close'   
exec @returnCode = sp_OADestroy @v_file
```

Error message returned by `sp_oageterrorinfo`:

> 0x8004271A, ODSOLE Extended Procedure, Error in srv_convert.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not use the OLE Automation stored procedures (i.e. `sp_OA*` ) as they have been deprecated since SQL Server 2005 was released. What you are trying to do is rather simple with SQLCLR (i.e. .NET-based objects that exist within SQL Server). You can create a scalar function to accept a filepath and return its bytes using the [File.ReadAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) method. Return that `byte[]` via the `SqlBytes` type.

You will need to set your Assembly to `PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS`. In order to accomplish that, please do *not* set the database to `TRUSTWORTHY ON` as that is an unnecessary security risk. Instead, sign the Assembly (using a password), then create an Asymmetric Key in the `master` Database from the DLL, then create a Login from that Key, and finally grant the Login the `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` permission.

For a lot more information on working with SQLCLR, including many examples, please see the series of articles I am writing on this topic on SQL Server Central: [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/) (that site does require free registration in order to read their content).

Or, if you don't want to deal with any coding, I created a library of over 270 functions and stored procedures called [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com/). There are several file system related functions, though none of them are available in the Free version. Still, the one that would help here is called: **File_GetFileBinary**.

Comment: Tanks for advice, but i don't want to use any other tools than SQL Server.
I found a solution with file split method which work in my case too.

Comment: @Mat That's fine. Just to be clear, SQLCLR is just as much SQL Server as the `sp_OA*` stored procs. You don't _need_ the [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com/) product that I sell as this particular function is easy enough to do on your own; it's only a few lines of code. The Assembly is loaded into the Database so it is backed up along with the data (unlike Extended Stored Procedures). Plus, SQLCLR is more efficient and secure than the OLE Automation procs. And they can use the newer datatypes and can easily return a `VARBINARY(MAX)`. You then do:`UPDATE tbl SET tbl.FileData=dbo.GetFile(tbl.path);`.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to pass a string that is greater than 4000 characters but less than or equal to 8000 characters in length to the sp_OASetProperty or to the sp_OAMethod OLE Automation extended stored procedure, the input string is silently truncated to 4000 characters before it is passed to the object and no error is returned.

If you try to set a property to a string that is greater than 8000 characters through the sp_OASetProperty OLE Automation extended stored procedure, or if you try to pass an input parameter to the sp_OAMethod OLE Automation extended stored procedure that is longer than 8000 characters, you receive the following error message:

```
  hr         Source                       Description
  ---------- ---------------------------- --------------------------
  0x8004271A ODSOLE Extended Procedure    Error in srv_convert.
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/325492

Answer (score 0):

If someone had same problem, i have done it like this:
In my procedure i create temp `#IMG` table:

```
create table #IMG (FileID2 nvarchar(50), img image)
```

If the file size is greater than 8k, i split it to parts in size 8000 and update #IMG:

```
    exec @returnCode = sp_oamethod @v_file, 'read', @v_buffer out, 8000
    update #IMG set img = @v_buffer
    SELECT @ptrval = TEXTPTR(Img) FROM #IMG WHERE FileID2 = @v_FileID2

    --file split section
    select  @v_Blocks = @v_FileSize/8000+1
    if @v_Blocks = 1
    begin
        WRITETEXT #IMG.Img  @ptrval @v_buffer
    end
    else
    begin 
        WRITETEXT #IMG.Img @ptrval @v_buffer
        set @j=@v_blocks-1
        while @j>0
        begin
            exec @returnCode = sp_oamethod @v_file, 'read',  @v_buffer out , 8000
            set @i=(select DATALENGTH(Img) from #IMG WHERE FileID2= @v_FileID2)
            UPDATETEXT  #IMG.Img @ptrval @i 0 @v_buffer 
        set @j=@j-1
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same workaround as described at [0x8004271A ODSOLE Extended Procedure Error in srv_convert.](http://jatindersingh.blogspot.ru/2014/04/0x8004271a-odsole-extended-procedure.html)

In your case, the line

```
exec @returnCode = sp_oamethod @v_file, 'read', @v_buffer out, -1
```

should be replaced by

```
Create table #tmp(dt varbinary(max))

insert into #tmp
exec @hr = sp_oamethod @v_file, 'read', @mode = -1

Select dt from #tmp -- single column/single row.
Drop Table #tmp -- clean up
```

Caution: this code wasn't tested. However the following code works fine for 32KB xml output:

```
Create table #tmp(dt xml)

insert into #tmp
exec @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseXML.XML'
/*
  Here is the trick: inserting from the returned result set, i.e.
  `insert into <table>(<columns>) select <columns>`
*/

Select dt from #tmp -- single column/single row.
Drop Table #tmp -- clean up
```

`responseXML.XML` returns the whole xml document after calling `MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.send`. The trick works according to section `Result Sets` of [sp_OAMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-oamethod-transact-sql).

When the `table` variable type is available, the code can be even shorter:

```
DECLARE @xml(val xml);
insert into @xml
exec @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseXML.XML'

Select * from @xml; -- just to see the output
```

I.e. there is no need to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same issue. Apparently, you cannot use `sp_OAMethod` with a VARBINARY(MAX) variable.
Try changing: `declare @v_buffer varbinary(max)`
to `declare @v_buffer varbinary(8000)`.

Good luck!